# Rasberry Pi bluetooth without pulseaudio

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, pulseaudio, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to control a stepper motor using a raspberry pi zeroW bluetooth serial port /dev/rfcomm0. I had it working perfectly but my phone, a Samsung Galaxy S10, diverted the audio from my cochlear implant to the Pi's pulseaudio system. I removed pulseaudio from the raspberry pi but now the S10 will only connect briefly while it tries to establish a A2DP. Then I get Authentication failure (0x05).
Here is the out put of bluetoothctl info <the phone's MAC> :

```
Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (public)
    Name: My Galaxy S10nn nb n.
    Alias: My Galaxy S10nn nb n.
    Class: 0x005a020c
    Icon: phone
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PANU                      (00001115-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: NAP                       (00001116-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: SIM Access                (0000112d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (a23d00bc-217c-123b-9c00-fc44577136ee)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v0075p0100d0201
```

here is some output from btmon:

```
> HCI Event: Simple Pairing Complete (0x36) plen 7          #1 [hci0] 36.851236
        Status: Authentication Failure (0x05)
        Address: 24:5A:B5:97:4B:7E (Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8   {0x0001} [hci0] 36.851434
        BR/EDR Address: 24:5A:B5:97:4B:7E (Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4              #2 [hci0] 36.856216
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 11
        Reason: LMP Response Timeout / LL Response Timeout (0x22)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8     {0x0001} [hci0] 36.856316
        BR/EDR Address: 24:5A:B5:97:4B:7E (Samsung Electronics Co.,Ltd)
        Reason: Unspecified (0x00)
< HCI Command: Write Scan Enable (0x03|0x001a) plen 1       #3 [hci0] 36.859507
        Scan enable: Page Scan (0x02)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                 #4 [hci0] 36.903301
      Write Scan Enable (0x03|0x001a) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
```

Tried putting this in rc.local, to no avail:

```
sudo bt-agent -d --capability=DisplayOnly -p /home/peter/pins
```